# C# How to AutomaticAuthentication in WebApp, which is using Azure AD for authentication?

Tags: authentication, owin, azure-active-directory

I am following the below sample to enable authentication using Azure AD:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

This example provides a signin option, when clicked does the authentication and recognizes the user.

Required behavior - What I am looking for is the user is automatically authenticated on entering the base Url.

Could someone help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual rules for ASP.NET authentication apply. For example, you can decorate your controller classes with [Authorize] - the first unauthenticated request will trigger the sign in flow.